# How to make users rate themselves in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

It's been a few days since I've been trying to create a part of a system, but I haven't been successful. I would like to have a guideline to get users to rate themselves (5-star rating) and make each user's grades in the database so I can manipulate them later. I am extending the AbstractUser class to add new information, another to evaluate with my user as fk, but I can't think more than that. If anyone can help me, I appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked  to me. I created a class wich extends a AbstractUser for my user, after I created a fk CustomUser into Rate class:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    imagem = StdImageField('Imagem', upload_to='photos', variations={
        'thumb':
            {
                'width': 100, 'height': 100, 'crop': True
            }
    })

    @property
    def avg_rating(self):
        # all_ratings = map(lambda x: x.rating, self.rate_set.all()) 
        return self.rate_set.all().aggregate(
            media=Avg('rating'))['media']

    @property
    def count_rating(self):
        return self.rate_set.all().count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


"""
    Class that represents the assessment itself. Here is the note, the user 
    who extends RatedUser - as if it were an extension of the User class 
    twice.
"""


class Rate(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    # RATING_CHOICES = zip(range(6), range(6))
    rated_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)
    # rating = models.SmallIntegerField(choice=RATING_CHOICES)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list_users')
```